# How to convert the date value taken from the date time picker to the Date column in SQL Server table in Visual C#?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2013

This is how I did the code but the error is in the variable `dob`. It says conversion failed when converting date from character to string.

```
try
{
    DialogResult dr = MessageBox.Show("Are you sure you want to update data?", "Confirm?", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo, MessageBoxIcon.Asterisk);

    if (dr == DialogResult.Yes)
    {
        int Stu_id = Convert.ToInt32(Stu_DataGrid.CurrentRow.Cells[0].Value.ToString());

        con.Open();
        string query = "Update tb_Student set Stu_Name = '"+name+"', Stu_DOB = '"+dob+"', Age = '"+age+"', Stu_Address = '"+Address+"', Stu_Tel_no = '"+telno+ "' Where Student_ID = '" + Stu_id + "'";

        MessageBox.Show(query); //This is to see whether the query is correct

        com = new SqlCommand(query, con);

        line = com.ExecuteNonQuery();
        com.Dispose();
        con.Close();

        if (line > 0)
        {
            loadGridData();
            ClearData();
            MessageBox.Show("Student with ID " + Stu_id + " updated successfully!", "Updated", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Exclamation);
        }
        else
            MessageBox.Show("Update Failed", "Failed", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
    }
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString());
}
```

Comment: [SQL Injection alert](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms161953%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) - you should **not** concatenate together your SQL statements - use **parametrized queries** instead to avoid SQL injection

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The simple answer: don't.

Let ADO.NET do it for you and protect your code from SQL injection at the same time [by using parameters](http://www.dreamincode.net/forums/topic/268104-parameterizing-your-sql-queries-the-right-way-to-query-a-database/):

Change your query to use the variable `@dob` then use this:

```
com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@dob", dob);
```

You should do that for all of your arguments too - instead of concatenating the string.

Reading material:

- [SQL Injection (Wikipedia)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection)
- [Parameterizing Your SQL Queries (DreamInCode)](http://www.dreamincode.net/forums/topic/268104-parameterizing-your-sql-queries-the-right-way-to-query-a-database/)

Comment: Yes it is DateTime dob. But still it gives me the error. but it does show in my MessageBox (temp one) that the date has been converted successfully. That's why I can't figure it out.

Answer (score 1):

Can't see what datatype of dob. If it is a date you can use the following to avoid date format issues in SQL Server:

```
dob.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd")
```

It's a more generic format that can't be misinterpreted since it's always obvious which is the month and which the day, despite of en-US setting or en-GB as default for the database.

You should use SqlParameters though to avoid SQL injection. If you would use that, you wouldn't have to convert date to an understandable string format yourself.

If dob is a string directly from the control, you should convert the string first to a DateTime, using the DateFormat from the DatePicker. This will also match the format if you have set a custom DateFormat initially.

Comment: Ok thanks it worked. Thanks all of you who helped me.

Comment: Remember that I did explain what went wrong. You should at least parse the input to a DateTime. That will avoid you using the text value itself and risk SQL injection. In addition you can use SqlParameter as suggested in my post. In Simon Whitehead's answer you can see an example of adding the DateTime dob as a SqlParameter.

Comment: yes true SqlParameters is easy to configure thanks :)